# Implement infinite scrolling with a listfragment that has Actionbar pull to refresh

Tags: android, android-listfragment, pull-to-refresh

I'm using action bar pull to refresh of Chris Banes, and when I use the scroll listener to detect the bottom, it doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
    Log.e("testing", "testing");
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    Log.e("testing", "testing");
}
```

None of the methods are triggered.

Is there a way to use it? Or pull to refresh retain the listener for its use?

Answer (score 0):

Done!

What I do was to enter this line

```
getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
```

in onActivityCreated method. When I use it in others method, it was called just once.